# Copy all sub-folders with a specified name into a merged folder using .bat

Tags: batch-file, copy, subdirectory

I would like to copy all sub-folders (including the contents of these folders) with the name "PHASE 1" and merge their contents in another location.

Example files in my current directory:

```
Folder 1\PHASE 1\test1.pdf
Folder 2\PHASE 1\test2.pdf
Folder 3\PHASE 1\test3.pdf
```

I would like these to be copied into a single directory like so:

```
MASTER FOLDER\PHASE 1
>test1.pdf
>test2.pdf
>test3.pdf
```

I would like to create a loop to repeat this process for PHASE 2, PHASE 3, etc.

This is all I have tried with no success:

```
for /r "%cd%" %%x in ("PHASE 1") do copy /y "%%x" ""%cd%"\MASTER FOLDER"
```

Comment: `"%cd%"` is not required. It is the default option. Also, `This is all I have tried with no success:` is not very descriptive. What you are getting?
Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for the response. All I am getting from the example code I have tried is "The system cannot find the file specified." @double-beep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a:d /b /s "PHASE *"') do (
    xcopy /y "%%~A" "MASTER FOLDER\%%~nxA\"
)
```

Look at `for /?` and you may see:

> **(set)**  Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.

`PHASE 1` is a folder name which seems to be an invalid value for `(set)`.

Instead of `for /r`, `for /f` using the `dir` command could get the
directory paths which match a wildcard pattern.

The code above uses `dir` to get the directories with `/a:d`,
recurse with `/s` and returns in bare format with `/b`.

The `for /f` option of `delims=` causes each path to be returned,
without spliting into tokens.

`xcopy` copies each matching directory path into the `MASTER FOLDER` directory.

If you need to ensure that the wildcard of the pattern `PHASE *` matches digits,
then `dir` could be piped to `findstr` to filter the returned paths.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works perfectly. The only change I made was adding a /s switch so that sub-folders are also copied. @michael_heath